# Сервис не получает координаты, когда телефон засыпает

Tags: android, геолокация

В моём приложении есть сервис, работает он в foreground, его основная задача получать координаты местоположения, в фоновом режиме всё норм, но когда телефон засыпает, координат нет, все остальные процессы работают. Использую Location Services

Comment: На какой версии ОС тестируете?

Comment: На Android 4.4.2